# load a few json elements at a time by scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, scrollview

I have a `ListFragment` that contains a list of items. I would like to load say 9 items at a time and when i scroll and reach the bottom of the listview i want to load another 9 items in background.

I make 2 request to my web server:

1) to get all the item id's of the items, by a searh() method

2) to get all the item details of a specific item though its id, by getId(id) method

The version i have implemented gets all the ids and then loads all the items at once in the doInBackground method of AsyncTask and it works. and it takes very long (i dont want a button because its really ugly).

I'd like to introduce this thing about the `onScrollListener` so that when i first open my app, in background i get all the ids, and then i get the first 9 items and show them. then when i scroll to the end i want to load the next 9 items. How do i do this?

I have read a few posts but it not clear to me, especially due to the fact that i have 2 functions that need to be run in background, 1 function needs to be run once while the other many times and i need to keep track of which id's i getting.

I would also if possible like to add the function that if i pull the `ListView` a little then it should update my view.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.adapter.ListViewAdapter;
import com.prjma.lovertech.util.MVPFunctions;


public class CompraFragment extends ListFragment  {


    public ListView listView;
    public ListViewAdapter adapter;

    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private DownloadTask mDownloadTask = null;

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;
    public Bitmap icon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compra, false); 
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compra, container, false); 

        // now you must initialize your list view
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 

        mDownloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        mDownloadTask.execute((Void) null);     


        return rootView;
    }


    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            //Here i get all the id's
            ArrayList<Long> ids = MVPFunctions.getMioSingolo().search();

            //for each id get all its details and put it in a map
            items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            for(int i=0; i < ids.size(); i++){
                items.add(MVPFunctions.getMioSingolo().getItem(ids.get(i)));
            }
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            /*
             * This is executed on UI thread before doInBackground(). It is
             * the perfect place to show the progress dialog.
             */
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Downloading Content...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mDownloadTask = null;

            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //showProgress(false);

            if (items.get(0).get("status error")!= null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "status error = " + items.get(0).get("status error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("status error put toast", (String) items.get(0).get("status error"));
                //fai qualcosa, tipo torna indietro, ecc
            }
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.listview_item_row, items, icon);
            // updating listview
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mDownloadTask = null;
            //showProgress(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.prjma.lovertech.R;
import com.prjma.lovertech.activity.DettagliActivity;
import com.prjma.lovertech.model.Item;

public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Context context; 
    public int layoutResourceId;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items;
    public Bitmap icon;

    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int listviewItemRow, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items, Bitmap icon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, listviewItemRow);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public Item getItem(Item position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (row == null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, null);       

            viewHolder.ic_thumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ic_thumbnail);
            viewHolder.scadenza = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvScadenza);
            viewHolder.prezzo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvPrezzo);
            viewHolder.followers = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowers);
            viewHolder.hProgressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.hProgressBar);

            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> item = items.get(position);
        viewHolder.ic_thumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) item.get("pic1m"));
        viewHolder.scadenza.setText((CharSequence) item.get("scadenza"));
        viewHolder.prezzo.setText((CharSequence) item.get("prezzo"));
        viewHolder.followers.setText((CharSequence) item.get("followers"));
        viewHolder.hProgressBar.setProgress((Integer) item.get("coefficient"));

        //row.onListItemClick(new OnItemClickListener1());
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return row;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private int mPosition;

        private OnItemClickListener(int position){
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.i("onListItemClickList", "Item clicked: " + mPosition);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Message " + Integer.toString(mPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DettagliActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("id", mPosition);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }   
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView prezzo;
        public TextView scadenza;
        public TextView followers;
        public ImageView ic_thumbnail;
        public ProgressBar hProgressBar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, check how close the user is from the bottom of the data set.  When they get to the end, call a method that fetches more items from the network.  I normally use a "REFRESH_THRESHOLD" integer to prefetch items before they're needed.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Item current = getItem(position);

    //Pre-fetch
    if(getCount() - position <= REFRESH_THRESHOLD){
        //If there are more items to fetch, and a network request isn't already underway
        if(is_loading == false && has_remaining_items == true){
            getItemsFromNetwork();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but does'nt this have to be done in the asyncTask class or in the Fragmentclass as it needs to be done in background? and how 2 i manage 2 different "heavy" calls to the server? can i use 2 asyckTasks? ill edit my question and add my adapter

Comment: It seems like the back end could be implemented more efficiently if you're having to make separate calls for the item id then then item's data.  Why couldn't this be consolidated into one JSON response?

Comment: Actually, from what you've said you'll already have all of the IDs when the adapter is initialized, and basically be paging through them as the user scrolls?

Comment: yes but before i show a screen with items i have to specify how many items to display and then keep on adding a fixed number when i reach the bottom of the scroll. all the examples that i find are using pages, but my resource is not divided into pages, therefore i need to get a few items at a time and display them

Comment: You could just go ahead and set the list adapter with an empty array list, then use my_adapter.add(item) as more data becomes available.  Doesn't seem like too complicated of a problem.  Also, since you have the entire set of IDs before you start requesting the underlying data, you could implement a paging mechanism on the front end...